# Не работает mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, wamp

Недавно решил перейти с denwer на wamp. Имеется .htaccess с содержанием

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

И он прекрасно работал под денвером. А вот под wamp отказывается, хоть там и включен rewrite_module. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`?

Comment: Что именно не работает? Нет переадресации или передачи параметра?

Comment: Переадресации нет

Comment: `AllowOverride ` для папки включен?

Comment: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so в конфиге имеется